# Why are polyfills in angular production builds behaving differently than in dev mode?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, polyfills

We use angular material for displaying a simple dialog. The problem occurs only in Internet Explorer 11 in combination with the core-js/es6/weak-map polyfill. First we forgot to include this polyfill but in dev mode the dialog still worked. But when we tested the production build the dialog did not open and throwed an error. Now it's clear for us that it should fail because of the missing polyfill. But why is it working in dev mode without the polyfill?

We have a sample cli based project to show the issue here: https://github.com/olmero/matdialog-ie11

You can run the project with "npm run start" and "npm run start-prod". Then comment out the WeakMap polyfill in polyfills.ts and compare.

Answer (score 0):

There was a polyfill change in v7. I don't know if it's related to your problem.

"Continuing our focus on performance, we analyzed common mistakes across the ecosystem. We discovered that many developers were including the reflect-metadata polyfill in production, which is only needed in development.

To fix this, part of the update to v7 will automatically remove this from your polyfills.ts file, and then include it as a build step when building your application in JIT mode, removing this polyfill from production builds by default."